# How to get rid of a variable in a list if its empty

Tags: python

I am trying to make a simple calculator that takes multiple values at once.

`A = input("Values separate with spaces")

a, b, c = A.split(' ')

print(a)`

Unless I input the exact amount of amount of items in the list  will get this error message: ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)

Is there a way to take more or less values?

Comment: yes, just use a list.  `myList = A.split()`. The title and the actual question are completely different things though

Comment: Yes but than how would I get the values from the list into separate variables?

Comment: you don't want to get those values into separate variables, instead you can access the values in the list by indexing (eg: first element is `myList[0]`, the second is `myList[1]`)

Comment: OK that works thanks for actually helping instead of criticizing.

Comment: I'm the only one who commented in your question.